# Auto frame splitting in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, customization

Certain `emacs` function splits the current frame, for example `magit-status` or `compile` (probably there are dozens). How `emacs` decides whether to do a *vertical* split or a *horizontal* one?

My experiments suggests that if the frame's width is larger then 162 chars then it dose a vertical split, and otherwise a horizontal one. Is it the right value? More important, where is this value stored, how can I change this threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `split-width-threshold`:
>
> Minimum width for splitting windows sensibly. Hide If this is an
>   integer, `split-window-sensibly` may split a window horizontally only
>   if it has at least this many columns.  If this is nil,
>   `split-window-sensibly` is not allowed to split a window horizontally.

Standard value is 160 here, looks pretty close to what you've found.